# Strapi v3, Microsoft/AAD authentication provider returns Not Found

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, strapi

A Strapi v3x is deployed on IIS and being served with a help of reverse proxy URL rewrite. Everything works fine, until a user navigates to http://mystrapiapp.com/connect/microsoft endpoint.

Instead of redirecting user to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id?...", the user gets navigated to "http://mystrapiapp.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id?...", which of course returns NOT FOUND.

**MyStrapiApp** in this case is the IIS website so obviously the url that is received as callback from "/connect/microsoft" gets overwritten along the way.

Has anyone managed to find a way how this be configured correctly?

Comment: You should first enable FRT to learn from where the rewrite happened, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Please show us the URL rewrite code in your web.config file.